# Can spark-defaults.conf resolve environment variables?

Tags: apache-spark

If I have a line like below in my `spark-env.sh` file

```
export MY_JARS==$(jars=(/my/lib/dir/*.jar); IFS=,; echo "${jars[*]}")
```

which gives me a comma delimited list of jars in `/my/lib/dir`, is there a way I can specify

```
spark.jars $MY_JARS
```

in the `spark-defaults.conf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** No, it cannot, but there *is* a solution.

Spark reads the `conf` file as a properties file without any additional env var substitution.

What you could do however is to write the computed value `MY_JARS` from `spark-env.sh` straight to `spark-defaults.conf` using `>>` (append). The last wins so no worry there could be many similar entries.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Spark 3+, there is a way to do this: `${env:VAR_NAME}`.

For instance if you want to add the current username to the Spark Metrics Namespace, add this to your spark-defaults.conf file:

```
spark.metrics.namespace=${env:USER}
```

The generated metrics will show the username instead of the default namespace:

```
 testuser.driver.BlockManager.disk.diskSpaceUsed_MB.csv
 testuser.driver.BlockManager.memory.maxMem_MB.csv
 testuser.driver.BlockManager.memory.maxOffHeapMem_MB.csv
 testuser.driver.BlockManager.memory.maxOnHeapMem_MB.csv
... etc ...
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/VariableSubstitution.html

> A helper class that enables substitution using syntax like ${var}, ${system:var} and ${env:var}.

Comment: Hi @Devon. Could you share any official document showing that env variables now supported and can be used in `spark-defaults.conf`? I've tried with `spark.driver.extraClassPath=${env:SPARK_CONF_DIR}` and it doesn't work for me. Supporting env variables would've solved many issues.

Comment: @mrDzurb I added a link in the answer text. The official docs don't seem to talk about it much, I had to go source-diving to find out this was actually supported. I am using `${env:USER}` currently for interpolated usernames, like I've put in the example.

Comment: spark.driver.host=${env:POD_IP}
this works for me, spark version:3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Spark 1.4 and did not worked. 
*spark-defaults.conf* is a Key/ value and looking the code it seems values are not evaluated.